# Can someone help me understand the key structure of this MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates

We have a 3 column table which I did not set up that basically just tracks timestamps.  Here is that table:

```
  | Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  | name  | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | type  | enum('start','end') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | time  | datetime            | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
```

Here is some sample data:

> | updateIDXfiletrans.php          | start | 2011-02-16 00:30:01 |
>
> | morningmarketingimportstart.php | start | 2011-02-16 00:30:01 |
>
> | updateIDXfiletrans.php          | end   | 2011-02-16 00:30:02 |
>
> | morningmarketingimportstart.php | end   | 2011-02-16 00:35:15 |

As you can see, none of the fields themselves are unique.  In fact, the only logical key structure for this table would be a multi-column key for all 3 columns, because that is the only thing that should be unique, the combination of all 3.  And this is what I assumed that the table had, because well... it's been working for like 3 years straight, so I didn't think the keys were set up wrong.

And then upon moving to a new server it repeatedly gets this error when we try to run imports:

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 51: Duplicate entry 'eod_blf-start' for key
>   'nameindex'

I went to check the index structure and this is what I found:

> | Table             | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index |
>   Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null |
>   Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
>
> | blfimporttracking |          1 | nameindex |            1 | name
>   | A         |          48 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
>   |               |
>
> | blfimporttracking |          1 | nameindex |            2 | type
>   | A         |          96 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
>   |               |
>
> | blfimporttracking |          1 | timeindex |            1 | time
>   | A         |       16920 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
>   |               |

Everything is the same on the old server and new server, yet only the new server is having the issue.  And I should also note that on each server we have the same set-up for three different companies (I double checked it today) and this is only happening on the one company's imports.

Basically, I don't understand what I'm looking at here.  Are nameindex and timeindex keys, or just indexes?  Whatever the case, should the way things are set up be causing a duplicate entry error?

For the heck of it I went into MySQL itself and just inserted the same data into the table in question multiple times and it all took fine.  So I'm very confused here.

Comment: Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` output from the new server?

Comment: | blfimporttracking | CREATE TABLE `blfimporttracking` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('start','end') DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `nameindex` (`name`,`type`),
  KEY `timeindex` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Comment: I'm looking at the show create table on the old server now and it is identical.  Our server guy thinks it is just some weird glitch and wants to rebuild the new server.  Which is fine and all but I'd like to understand what happened as much as possible.

Comment: I suspected something like this.  But then... why does it work on the other server, and why does it work for the other 2 companies on this server?  For instance, here is some sample data on the new server (that was copied over from the old one) for that table... same name and type for everything, just different times.
| morning_blf | end   | 2014-05-08 07:51:46 |
| morning_blf | end   | 2014-05-09 07:55:42 |
| morning_blf | end   | 2014-05-12 08:32:35 |
| morning_blf | end   | 2014-05-13 07:47:00 |

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused now... where is it defining any of these columns as unique?  A key is basically just an index if it is not a unique key, right?

Comment: Yes, a key is just and index.  It would have to have the UNIQUE keyword to be a unique index.

Comment: So there isn't anything on this table that shouldn't allow duplicates right?!  Which kind of matches the results I get when adding duplicates directly in MySQL.  This error is confounding.